# Stuck with an error while installing Strapi app

Tags: node.js, npm, strapi

I am not able to create a strapi app using the command npx create-strapi-app@latest my-project --quickstart. I tried several times, but sometimes, it is stuck at installing dependencies or sometimes it failed to install by saying that this module is deprecated or not found.
Someone please help me with this!!

```
Error while installing dependencies:
warning @strapi/strapi > koa-session > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
warning @strapi/strapi > koa-body > formidable@1.2.6: Please upgrade to latest, formidable@v2 or formidable@v3! Check these notes: 
warning @strapi/strapi > @strapi/admin > react-router > mini-create-react-context@0.4.1: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
warning @strapi/strapi > @strapi/admin > node-polyfill-webpack-plugin > url > querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
warning @strapi/strapi > @strapi/plugin-email > @strapi/provider-email-sendmail > sendmail > mailcomposer@3.12.0: This project is unmaintained
warning @strapi/strapi > @strapi/plugin-email > @strapi/provider-email-sendmail > sendmail > mailcomposer > buildmail@3.10.0: This project is unmaintained
warning @strapi/strapi > @strapi/generators > plop > liftoff > findup-sync > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
warning @strapi/strapi > @strapi/generators > plop > liftoff > findup-sync > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
warning @strapi/strapi > @strapi/generators > plop > liftoff > findup-sync > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning @strapi/strapi > @strapi/generators > plop > liftoff > findup-sync > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
warning @strapi/plugin-users-permissions > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning @strapi/plugin-users-permissions > request > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
warning @strapi/plugin-users-permissions > request > har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
warning "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions > @strapi/helper-plugin@4.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^5.74.0".
error C:\Users\adity\OneDrive\Desktop\my-pro\node_modules\better-sqlite3: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: prebuild-install || npm run build-release
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Users\adity\OneDrive\Desktop\my-pro\node_modules\better-sqlite3
Output:
prebuild-install warn install No prebuilt binaries found (target=18.12.0 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)

> better-sqlite3@7.4.6 build-release
> node-gyp rebuild --release

gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
gyp info using node@18.12.0 | win32 | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.0 found at "C:\Users\adity\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:364:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:385:16
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:420:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22621
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\adity\OneDrive\Desktop\my-pro\node_modules\better-sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v18.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok

 Keep trying!

Oh, it seems that you encountered errors while installing dependencies in your project.
Don't give up, your project was created correctly.
Fix the issues mentioned in the installation errors and try to run the following command:

cd C:\Users\adity\OneDrive\Desktop\my-pro && yarn install
```

Comment: Temp Fix: I solved this by spinning up a VSCode Node/Postrgress DevContainer then immediately installing webpack globally. The install finished. When the bug is fixed, I can remove webpack as a global package.

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to node version, and only v14 seems to work. Though strapi's docs state that v16 and v18 are supported, it also states that you need npm v6 ONLY.

So here's what worked for me:

```bash
nvm install 14
```

And this will install v14 on your local device - note that it doesn't replace your existing node (maybe you have v18 ?). nvm allows you to use multiple node versions and switch between them as required.

```bash
nvm use 14
```

It will return the following:

> Now using node v14.21.2 (npm v6.14.17)

now run:

```bash
npx create-strapi-app project-name
```

It should install and open up localhost for strapi admin in your browser

Answer (score 0):

switch to Node v14 <= v16.x.x and then try again

The issue might be because your Node version is >v16